# Is there DEVICE_PERFORMANCE_REPORT in Google AdWords API

Tags: php, api, google-ads-api

I've been searching information about devices at least 2 days, and still havent found it.

All reports are listed there.
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/all-reports

Is there a way to get device report somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `DEVICE_PERFORMANCE_REPORT`, but your can add the `Device` field to pretty much every existing report to segment your data by device.

If all you care about is overall numbers per device type, just create an `ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT`, define the metrics you are interested in and add the `Device` field. You'll receive a report with 3 rows, one for every device type.